# Android Google Maps Directions API - returns multiple route options but not waypoints

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

When I use Google Maps Directions API, it returns multiple route options with duration in traffic, distance etc but does not include any waypoint for the routes. 
"waypoint_order" is an empty array in the JSON response.

How do I retrieve the route options in a way that I get the waypoints also for each route ? Appreciate your help in resolving this.

Comment: Do you need the list of LatLng for the route to draw it as a polyline?

Comment: Thanks, I got it ! I can use the LatLng list to re-draw the route !